# What event is fired when a Mediator is Registered?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, puremvc, flexunit4

I wrote the following test for my PureMVC project

```
[Test]
public function facadeCanRegisterMediator():void {

    if(!Facade.getInstance().hasMediator(NewReelMediator.NAME)) {

        Facade.getInstance().registerMediator(new NewReelMediator());
    }
    assertTrue(Facade.getInstance().hasMediator(NewReelMediator.NAME));
}
```

However it is always failing.  What event do I need to be listening for before I check that the facade has the mediator?  Or is there some other reason it is failing?

I get the message "expected true but was false".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel stupid!

The answer to my question is that I left out the name of the Mediator when registering it!

The proper code should be:

```
[Test]
public function facadeCanRegisterMediator():void {

    if(!Facade.getInstance().hasMediator(NewReelMediator.NAME)) {

        Facade.getInstance().registerMediator(new NewReelMediator(NewReelMediator.NAME));
    }
    assertTrue(Facade.getInstance().hasMediator(NewReelMediator.NAME));
}
```

which of course... passes.  Events have nothing to do with it.
There is no event which is fired when a mediator is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` is fired before mediator is registered.

When ever you view added to stage that time only your mediator class registered.

```
view.addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE , addedToStageHandler );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know what is causing the delay between the registration and the "hasMediator" property.